# Shortening URLs using goo.gl and Tasker

Tags: tasker, https

I'm trying to use Tasker to shorten URLs. Previously, I don't think this was possible, but v1.3 added support for https.

I've tried following the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#shorten and I did get an HTTP 400 code, but the %HTTPD variable returned %HTTPD.

The things I used in Tasker were:

```
HTTP Post
Server:Port    https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIzaSyA8FwOcH-qW6ACR27H_wlrNKcv2OUl_Z8c
Data / File    "longUrl":"http://www.google.com/"
Content Type   application/json

Flash
Text           %HTTPR

Flash
Text           %HTTPD
```

Comment: Mind if I ask why would you need to do this?

Comment: I have a little task which copies your location and a maps link to the clipboard for emailing or for SMS. I got that to work, now I'm trying to add a link-shortening option so I can send them to people who don't have internet on their phone. Also, just for the challenge.

Comment: How do you suppose to get access token using Tasker?

Comment: I should only need the API key, given that I'm not requesting private data. I've added the API key to my request, with the same results.